# How do I test Digest::SHA2.hexdigest in online irb?

Tags: ruby, irb

I want to see the hash created by the function Digest::SHA2.hexdigest. I do not have Ruby installed, so I went for the online irb. Typing

```
Digest::SH­A2.hexdige­st("hello"­)
```

gives

```
=> #<NameError: uninitialized constant Digest>
```

Is it possible to add the needed library in any online irb?

Comment: What do you mean with "online irb"?

Comment: Sorry. I was recommended in another question to test Ruby functions online in order to see if the return value match the C# code I write. I used the website http://tryruby.org/ to write the Ruby code in the browser.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do as below :

```
2.0.0-p0 :003 > require 'digest'
 => true 
2.0.0-p0 :004 > Digest::SHA2.hexdigest("hello")
 => "2cf24dba5fb0a30e26e83b2ac5b9e29e1b161e5c1fa7425e73043362938b9824" 
2.0.0-p0 :005 >
```

So do first `require 'digest'`.

Try in [**tutorialspoint**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_comments.htm)

[image]

Comment: Sorry. I tried the: require 'digest'. But it says: <NoMethodError: undefined method 'require' for main:Object>. I used tryruby.org.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have something to test on.